# Cordova plugin that allow users to browse files and upload the selected files (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Is there a plugin Cordova that allow users to browse files, pick a file and upload it on iOS? I found only 3 plugins: File Opener 2 plugin, Cordova plugin file and  File Transfer plugin but they do not meet my need. 
Did anyone do that ?

Comment: what's missing that doe not satisfy your needs?

Comment: In my app, I want users to be able to browse the files in IPhone and choose the desired file. It is something like Cordova Plugin Camera. It provide a access (or an interface) that allow you to browse and choose the images from the gallery.

Answer (score 4):

**iOS**

Quote from Mike Harrington (Ionic Developer Advocate)

> For iOS, you sadly don't have a file browser/chooser.
>
> Not going to be possible sadly.

[source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recommended-android-ios-file-chooser-plugin/20761/3)

But (same source) according to a user on the same forum

> Apparently there's this one, haven't tried it and sadly it's only for
>   iOS8 (and higher?):
>
> [FilePicker-PhoneGap-iOS-Plugin](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin)
>
> Anyway I suppose that if you understand the physical file system
>   structure of iOS and you have the time then you could always build a
>   UI yourself using the Cordova File plugin. Don't know about iCloud and
>   so on though.
>
> By the way, I tried [Cordova-filechooser](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) and it worked perfectly.
>
> The other [one](https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser) seems more
>   complicated to set up and gave me build errors on my initial attempt,
>   so I went with the other one.

---

**Android**

Using the `cordova-filechooser` plugin in combination with the File Transfer will probably resolve your issue.

Image taken from `cordova-filechooser`'s [git repo](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser)

[image]

Use this to select your files. Use File Transfer to transfer them.

---

Comment: I need this ASAP and i **cannot** add this plugin. cordova add plugin fails saying the repo can't be fetched. access denied, something about a public key. for the love of god someone help with this :)